# Paypal Express Checkout redirects to cart for United States

Tags: checkout, paypal

I have setup Paypal Express and that works fine if I create an order for Germany (Merchant Country) and some other countries.

But if I select United States in step "2. Billing Information" I get a wrong redirected after step "5. Payment Information". Instead of Paypal I get redirected to /checkout/cart.

In `/var/log/exception.log` i found:

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'PayPal NVP gateway
>   errors: The field Shipping Address State is required (#10729: Shipping
>   Address State Empty). Correlation ID: 15fb525b60ff5. Version: 72.0.'
>   in htdocs/app/Mage.php:579

Comment: Looks like some error in the payment process. Is there anything in the logs? Or a "payment transaction failed" mail being sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a NoState plugin installed. After uninstalling it the problem disappeared.

Comment: Please mark this answer as solution - klick on the check on the lieft side.

Comment: Your mention of the NoState plugin saved me. Turns out my state field was being hidden by an extension but I would have never thought to look for a missing form field at checkout. Thanks! The weird thing was I'm not using NoState... Not sure which extension is attempting to hide my state field.