# For Which Countries Does PayPal Require a State?

Tags: paypal, paypal-express, paypal-plus

When using PayPal (no matter which integration I think), we sometimes get the following error:

```
PAYPAL GATEWAY HAS REJECTED REQUEST. THE FIELD SHIPPING ADDRESS STATE IS REQUIRED (#10729: SHIPPING ADDRESS STATE EMPTY).
```

This was already the case for China and Japan. So we added these countries to the list of countries where the state is required (under System - Configuration - General). But for which countries does PayPal also require the state field? I guess there are more. We also asked the PayPal merchant support, but they could not give us any information (screw you, guys!). Maybe someone else has a complete list or we can build up one together?

Comment: Australia as well :)

Comment: There is a similar question where the "NoState" plugin worked (don't know that that is btw): http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/paypal-express-checkout-redirects-to-cart-for-united-states

Comment: I know the plugin does not answer your initial question, but maybe it helps :)

Comment: Just did a bit of googling and it seems this is kept a good secret.

Comment: Please refer this link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/country_codes/

Comment: @RaviThanki I do not see any information there which says which countries require a state...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following countries are known to require a state by PayPal:

- Argentinia
- Australia
- Canada
- China
- Hong Kong
- India
- Indonesia
- Japan
- Mexico
- Russia
- Switzerland
- Thailand
- United States

Comment: Switzerland is not requited as far as I know

Comment: India required the state.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following on the PayPal developer site: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/state_codes/

Comment: Thanks. But I do not think that the list is complete - many of the countries, where I know that they require a state, are not listed.

Comment: From testing the list in the developers guide seems to run true in the UK - for example Australia in the list you gave above is not required to have a state.  However, these things have a way of coming back to haunt you.  Therefore it might be the best option to set the State as a required field for all countries as customers will "fill it in"  if required to get to through checkout and this would also cover you in the event that PayPal updates it's policy per country.

Comment: Interesting point! Maybe PayPal requires different fields depending on the seller's location - although this does not make any sense to me. Requiring a state for all countries is a tough decision - the less customers need to do, the better the conversion rate.

Comment: May be 10736 is a recoverable error and therefore  the customer could be  re-directed back to PayPal to correct the address and continue with check out. See https://www.thinklikeamage.com/index.php/articles/magento/11-paypal-express-checkout-recoverable-failures

Comment: Reference to my comment above.  10736 is a non-recoverable error but the module I gave the link to enables the customer to correct the state without having to restart the checkout process.

Answer (score -1):

At the time of Paypal Express Checkout the customer enter City, State, and Postal Code if these three are not match the Paypal throws an error.

i.e, PayPal gateway has rejected request. A match of the Shipping Address City, State, and Postal Code failed (#10736: Shipping Address Invalid City State Postal Code) But Some of the Clients don’t want this validation.

For that you do changes on you Paypal module Api.

The change is `/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php` file

in `callSetExpressCheckout()` Method

remove the line `$request[\’ADDROVERRIDE\’] = 1;`

after that your customer use the Paypal checkout with not matching of state , city and postal code it’s working fine.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the concrete question.